# ng-repeat not outputting array results

Tags: angularjs

I'm still fairly new at this, but I'm having issues getting my ng-repeat to output book.review and book.stars. Can anyone point out what's wrong? Even if I put something like just a word in the ng-repeat like for instance

Test Word

Test Word never renders on the screen.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="DirectivesTest">
    <head>
        <title>Directives Practice</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            The #1 Book Review Site With Only 6 Books!
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div ng-controller="BookController">
                        <div class="test" ng-repeat="book in books">
                            {{book.review}}

                            {{book.stars}}
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <book-reviews></book-reviews>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('DirectivesTest', []);

app.directive('bookReviews', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'book-reviews.html',
        controller: 'BookController' //controller function
    }; //end return
}) //end directive

app.controller("BookController", [ '$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.books = [{
        $scope.title: "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
        $scope.description: "Harry Potter has no idea how famoushe  is. That's because he's being raised by his miserable aunt and uncle who are terrified Harry will learn that he's really a wizard, just as his parents were. But everything changes when Harry is summoned to attend an infamous school for wizards, and he begins to discover some clues about his illustrious birthright. From the surprising way he is greeted by a lovable giant, to the unique curriculum and colorful faculty at his unusual school, Harry finds himself drawn deep inside a mystical world he never knew existed and closer to his own noble destiny.",
        $scope.review: [
            {
                $scope.stars: 5,
                $scope.body: "I love this book!",
                $scope.author: "JoeJohnson@gmail.com",
                $scope.createdOn: 42434343
            },
            {
                $scope.stars: 4,
                $scope.body: "It was pretty good. A little long though",
                $scope.author: "PaulPaulson@gmail.com",
                $scope.createdOn: 42434343  
            },
            {
                $scope.stars: 5,
                $scope.body: "It's the best book I've ever read.",
                $scope.author: "JimJohnson@gmail.com",
                $scope.reatedOn: 454535543
            }
        ]
    }];

}])
```

Comment: you need to store `books` on the `$scope` if you want to access it from the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use $scope to provide the bindings between the controller and the view.

In your case:

```
...
app.controller("BookController", function($scope){
$scope.books = [{
...
```

Comment: I updated code to reflect changes above. I almost have it. I now have it saying {{book.review}} {{book.stars}} instead of nothing so that's progress, but it's still not pulling the variables. Any ideas?

Comment: Remove the $scope from the properties inside the books object, only books has to be scoped.

Comment: One question though. How come in your example you don't put BookController", ['$scope' and only put it in the function parameter

Comment: The name of the injected object is for minification of your javascript. When you minify your app, the objects injected ($scope, $http...) are turned into a, b, c variables. Because of that, angular doesn't know what to inject. So, we provide ['$scope', '$http'...] for that case. Since your code is not being minified, it's not necessary.

Comment: Glad I could help! If it solved your problem, cogitate accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller("BookController", function($scope){
$scope.books = [{
  title: "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
  description: "Harry Potter has no idea how famoushe  is. That's because he's being raised by his miserable aunt and uncle who are terrified Harry will learn that he's really a wizard, just as his parents were. But everything changes when Harry is summoned to attend an infamous school for wizards, and he begins to discover some clues about his illustrious birthright. From the surprising way he is greeted by a lovable giant, to the unique curriculum and colorful faculty at his unusual school, Harry finds himself drawn deep inside a mystical world he never knew existed and closer to his own noble destiny.",
    review: [{
        stars: 5,
        body: "I love this book!",
        author: "JoeJohnson@gmail.com",
        createdOn: 42434343
    },
    {
        stars: 4,
        body: "It was pretty good. A little long though",
        author: "PaulPaulson@gmail.com",
        createdOn: 42434343 
    },
    {
        stars: 5,
        body: "It's the best book I've ever read.",
        author: "JimJohnson@gmail.com",
        createdOn: 454535543
    }]
}];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="BookController" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div class="test" ng-repeat="book in books">
        <h4>{{book.title}}</h4>
        {{book.description}}
        <div ng-repeat="review in book.review">
            <hr/>
            Stars: {{review.stars}}, {{review.body}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you need to put books on the $scope. Also you may want to set up another ng-repeat inside the first one for the reviews.

```
<div ng-repeat="review in book.review">
```

then to print the stars of each review use

```
{{review.stars}}
```

In regards to your last edit, only book needs to be on the scope. not the variables inside the object.

```
    $scope.books = [{
        title: "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
        description: "Harry Potter has no idea how famoushe  is. That's because he's being raised by his miserable aunt and uncle who are terrified Harry will learn that he's really a wizard, just as his parents were. But everything changes when Harry is summoned to attend an infamous school for wizards, and he begins to discover some clues about his illustrious birthright. From the surprising way he is greeted by a lovable giant, to the unique curriculum and colorful faculty at his unusual school, Harry finds himself drawn deep inside a mystical world he never knew existed and closer to his own noble destiny.",

         review: [{
            stars: 5,
            body: "I love this book!",
            author: "JoeJohnson@gmail.com",
            createdOn: 42434343
},
{
    stars: 4,
    body: "It was pretty good. A little long though",
    author: "PaulPaulson@gmail.com",
    createdOn: 42434343  
},
{
    stars: 5,
    body: "It's the best book I've ever read.",
    author: "JimJohnson@gmail.com",
    reatedOn: 454535543

}
]
        }];
```